Getting Work Items in Azure DevOps with the Team responsible
I would like to get a list of work items in Azure DevOps Services with a column displaying the team responsible for every work item. This seems to be impossible!! I don't mind to use any technology available (REST, OData, Queries, ...) but I cannot find any way of doing it.
The work items have an Area Path and they are assigned to Teams, so in SQL it would be like a simple join between the tables, but not so with the Azure DevOps queries.
Any ideas?

I don't believe there is a "simple" way of doing this. But, considering you seem to be open to explore wider options to achieve the result, we should be able to do this if you are ok to do some additional wrapper scripting, say with Python. We can get team-to-area paths mapping using the classification-nodes API (ref https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/api-for-listing-team-areas/558934). And can get the work items along with area paths via normal route. Then we will need to join the two datasets within the wrapper script. Indeed, wish it was a simple join however!

@Raul, Have you tried the OData query shared in my answer below? Is it working for you?

Sorry, @BrightRan-MSFT. Yes, thank you!!! the query is working and now I can get my KPIs working

You can use the OData query like as below:
Before you use this OData query, ensure you are the member of Project Administrators group so that you can access and manage teams in the Azure DevOps project.
 
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?$select=WorkItemId, WorkItemType, Title, State, TagNames&$expand=AssignedTo($select=UserEmail), Area($select=AreaPath), Iteration($select=IterationPath), Teams($select=TeamName)&$filter=({some filters})

For example, below sample is to list work items assigned to a specified area path and show the names of teams that the work items belong to.
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?$select=WorkItemId, WorkItemType, Title, State, TagNames&$expand=AssignedTo($select=UserEmail), Area($select=AreaPath), Iteration($select=IterationPath), Teams($select=TeamName)&$filter=(Area/AreaPath eq 'PrimaryProj\Admin')

Result:

If the area path has been assigned to multiple teams, it will list all the teams which the area path is assigned to.



Great answer thanks, as I couldn't find any other info related to this. But I need user login, not email. Is this possible?

It may be available through process customization and work item rules.

Add a new field for a team value: Add and manage fields
Then add a rule to calculate your team through Area ID:



Area ID you may find in query results:


